# Concatenating two arrays of strings?

Tags: c, arrays, merge, memcpy

I am new to the c world and I want to merge two arrays into one array, i have one idea how to do this, but it doesnt work :P

```
char *s_one[] = { "Zorro", "Alex", "Celine" };
char *s_two[] = { "Zorro1", "Alex1"};

char *p = (char*)malloc((sizeof(s_one)+sizeof(s_two))*sizeof(char));
memcpy(p, s_one, sizeof(s_one));
memcpy(p + sizeof(s_one), s_two, sizeof(s_two));

//print out
for (count = 0; count < sizeof(p); count++)
        printf("\narr[%d] = %c.", count, p[count]);
```

the output is just some random characters...
what i am doing wrong, thanks in advance for every tipp

the output should be:
Zorro
Alex
Celine
Zorro1
Alex1

Comment: char * x [] is actually an array of pointers.  So your malloc() call should be multiplying the combined size of the two arrays by the size of a char * and not char.  That may not fix the issue, but it's likely to be a problem.

Comment: Your output specification clearly indicates you are NOT trying to merge these two arrays of strings. You are trying to concatenate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using memcpy I would recommend to iterate over each of the two arrays and copy one string from the source array into p using strcpy.  The problem of memcpy is that it should omit to copy the \0 character, hence your random characters.

You malloc instruction is fine.

Comment: I like your suggestion about iterating over the arrays.  But the malloc instruction is actually broken in that it multiplies by sizeof(char) instead of sizeof(char*).

Answer (score 2):

Let's see if I can get this right...

`s_one` is an array of `char *`.  So, your `sizeof()` and `memcpy()` operations are likely operating on the pointers, not the strings that they point to somewhere else in memory.  Then, when you go and `printf()` you are printing the pointers as characters rather than the strings they point to (as strings).  Not sure here, but perhaps this would work?

```
printf("\narr[%d] = %s.", count, *p[count]);
```

If you don't get it fixed before I get home, I'll test it out and see.

---

Combine with Marvo's comment about the `sizeof()` calls.

---

It really depends on what you want, but here's my attempt since I said I would post it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *s_one[] = { "Zorro", "Alex", "Celine" };
    char *s_two[] = { "Zorro1", "Alex1"};

    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(s_one));
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(s_two));

    int numberOfEntries = (sizeof(s_one) + sizeof(s_two)) / sizeof(char*);
    char **p = (char **)malloc(numberOfEntries);

    printf("%d\n", numberOfEntries);

    memcpy(p, s_one, sizeof(s_one));
    memcpy(p + sizeof(s_one)/sizeof(char *), s_two, sizeof(s_two));

    //print out
    int count = 0;
    for (count = 0; count < numberOfEntries; count++)
        printf("arr[%d] = %s.\n", count, p[count]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two arrays of pointers to `char` (actually pointing to the first character of a 0-terminated `char[]`). So when you `memcpy` from `s_one` and `s_two` to `p`, you copy the pointers, and what you print out are parts of the pointer values.

If you declared

```
char **p = malloc(sizeof s_one + sizeof s_two);
```

you'd get an array of five `char*`, pointing to the respective strings.

If you want to concatenate the strings that the elements of `s_one` resp. `s_two` point to, you need to allocate enough to hold the result (plus the 0-terminator):

```
size_t needed = 1;
for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof s_one / sizeof *s_one; ++i)
    needed += strlen(s_one[i]);
for((size_t i = 0; i < sizeof s_two / sizeof *s_two; ++i)
    needed += strlen(s_two[i]);
char *p = malloc(needed);
if (!p) {
    // allocation failed
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
p[0] = 0;
for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof s_one / sizeof *s_one; ++i)
    strcat(p,s_one[i]);
for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof s_two / sizeof *s_two; ++i)
    strcat(p,s_two[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just two tips for a less noisy malloc:
You don't need to cast it's return value. 
You don't need the sizeof(char) as a char by definition is 1 byte.

Answer (score 0):

my first solution is to iterate over each of the two arrays and copy one string from the source array into p using strcpy... thanks to Hernan Velasquez

```
char *s_one[] = { "Zorro", "Alex", "Celine" };
char *s_two[] = { "Zorro1", "Alex1"};

char *p[sizeof(s_one)/sizeof(char *) + sizeof(s_two)/sizeof(char *)];
memset(p, 0, sizeof(p));
for(count=0;count < sizeof(s_one)/sizeof(char *) ;count++) {
    p[count] = (char*)malloc((strlen(s_one[count])+1)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(p[count], s_one[count]);
}
i=count;
for(count=0;count < sizeof(s_two)/sizeof(char *) ;count++) {
    p[i] = (char*)malloc((strlen(s_two[count])+1)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(p[i], s_two[count]);
    i++;
}

//print out
for (count = 0; count < sizeof(p)/sizeof(char *); count++)
        printf("\narr[%d] = %s.", count, p[count]);
```

i think it is not very clean, but it works for me...
tomorow i try it with the tipp from Daniel Fischer